# Way to monitor the time elapsed throughout an arbitrary evaluation?

Tags: function-construction, monitoring

I'd like to have some way to view the time elapsed since the beginning of a long evaluation, viewable while the computation is still evaluating.

My first thought was to use `Monitor`, but it seems to require a variable's value to update before updating the display.  That is, I can't just provide it an expression I'd like re-evaluated 'continuously' throughout the computation:

```
With[{start=Now},
    Monitor[ 
        Table[Length[FactorInteger[2^n - 1]], {n, 50, 450, 50}],
        DateDifference[start, Now, "Second"]
    ]
]
```

[image: Failed attempt -- timing value doesn't update]

(Example computation slightly modified from the first example in the docs for `Monitor`.)  During evaluation, the `Monitor` cell never updates from its initial value -- see above.

Fine -- looks like I was expecting `Monitor` to do something it doesn't.  One would expect it to be difficult for such a function to determine how often to re-evaluate the expression to be monitored anyway.

Then the question becomes whether there's a way to do what I wanted `Monitor` to do -- evaluate an expression 'continuously' and display its updated value.

Of course, I don't really want this function updated continuously -- just every second or 10th of a second or so, ideally with a configurable duration.  Obviously I don't want this monitoring to slow down my computation in any non-neglible sense.

Note in particular that I do not wish to modify the expression being monitored to provide any sort of report on its progress, or anything like that.  I want this method to track the evaluation of an arbitrary expression.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133182/timing-evaluation-times-dynamically

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your answer there completely solves the X in my XY problem (+1 -- it's what I ended up using), but I like that CarlWoll solves my 'Y' issue with `Monitor`.

Comment: The funny thing is that I was using a variant in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169750/nintegration-and-globaladaptive-method/169926#169926) (`PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{mr, Clock[Infinity]};` about halfway down), and just after posting it, I saw your Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) with an [`UpdateInterval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpdateInterval):

```
SetAttributes[timed,HoldAll]
timed[expr_] := With[{start = AbsoluteTime[]},
    PrintTemporary @ Dynamic[AbsoluteTime[]-start, UpdateInterval->.1];
    expr
]
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Even though MicaelE2's [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145607/11035)'s use of `Clock` is what I ultimately went with, I really like the way `PrintTemporary` and `Dynamic` with `UpdateInterval` does exactly what I was hoping `Monitor` would do.  This is useful to me.